# Como retirar style do summernote

Tags: javascript, css, html5, summernote

Olá, estou usando o summernote e colocando um width numa div só que quando eu salvo meu style simplesmente some e ele coloca um outro no lugar. Vou mandar foto e também meu código html.

```
<div class="div-btn" style="width:100%!important;"></div>
```

Esse acima é o meu código mas ele se transforma nisso quando eu salvo:

```
<div class="div-btn" style="width: 483px; color: rgb(54, 54, 54); font-size: 16.6px; text-align: center !important;"></div>
```

Já fiz de tudo, até usei javascript mas não sei pq não funciona.
Vou mandar como tá meu javascript também.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#salvar').click(function() {
  var texto = $('#msg_consulta_marcacao').code();
  var div = $('div-btn');
  div.find('*').removeAttr('style');
  div.find('*').removeAttr("style").attr("style","width");

  textoConteudo = $(texto.replace(/&nbsp;|<br>/g, ' ')).text().trim();
  if(textoConteudo.length <= 0) {
    $('#msg_consulta_marcacao').html("");
  }
  else{
    $('#msg_consulta_marcacao').html($('#msg_consulta_marcacao').code());
  }
  
  this.disabled=true;
  this.form.submit();

}
);

  $('#padrao').summernote({
    height: 430,
    toolbar: [
            ]
  });

  $("#msg_consulta_marcacao").summernote({
  height: 400,
  toolbar: [
                ["style", ["style"]],
                ["font", ["bold", "underline", "clear"]],
                ["fontname", ["fontname"]],
                ["color", ["color"]],
                ["para", ["ul", "ol", "paragraph"]],
                ["table", ["table"]],
                ["insert", ["link", "picture"]],
                ["view", ["codeview"]]
            ],
  hint: {
    words: ['primeironome_pcte', 'nome_pcte', 'nome_profissional', 'data_agendamento', 'hora_agendamento', 'procedimento_agendamento', 'local_agendamento', 'endereco_agendamento'],
    match: /\b(\w{1,})$/,
    search: function (keyword, callback) {
      callback($.grep(this.words, function (item) {
        return item.indexOf(keyword) === 0;
      }));
    }
  }
});

  });
```

[image]

Obrigada!

Comment: Parece que vc está tentando tirar o width pelo JS, mas tente na verdade colocar um `min-width:100%` nele. No css o min-width sobrescreve o width, pode ser que funcione. E me parece que esse seletor está errado! `var div = $('div-btn');` não seira `var div = $('.div-btn');` com um `.` no nome da classe

Comment: Eu corrigi e fiz o que você falou mas ainda assim não funcionou :(

Comment: Talvez o plugin js do summernote esteja adicionando este valor e sobrescrevendo o seu "width". Tente adicionar este valor a sua class div-btn. Ex: ".div-btn {width:100%!important;}" no seu css.